# Fonts are blured in fullscreen Flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, fullscreen

I'm having the following problem. when I switch to fullscreen - all my fonts are blurred. I use the following code to enter fullscreen:

```
stage.fullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle( ... );

stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
```

I've tried with embed fonts, with `antialiastype = advanced` but there was no difference.

When I right-click and choose Zoom In the fonts are not blurred - can I achieve the same effect - no blurred fonts in fullscreen mode?

Here are some images:

img1.jpg - original

img2.jpg - fullscreen - blured fonts

img3.jpg - Zoom in - the fonts are ok

[image]

Comment: This is interesting. Did you tried to set your screen aspect ratio to match the aspect ratio of your stage and see how it looks then?

Comment: Hi, 10x for the suggestion I've tried it but there was no change - the fonts are still blured.

Comment: Hym, Now I think its reasonable behavior. Because as you enter full_screen mode the the stage visible area should stay the same - this means it have to be scaled up and the is done on final window frame (for performance reasons I guess). On the other hand when you zoom in you are cropping visible stage region. What you want your result to be you want scale the view without bluring vecotrs and fonts or just what the content to use full size of screen. Did you see [stage.ScaleMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using advanced settings. Set the textFields antiAliasType to `flash.text.AntiAliasType.ADVANCED`. And then set the textField `sharpness` property to 400.  See the [documentation here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#sharpness).

And I would say yes, use embedFonts = true

Comment: Hi, my fonts are already embeded and with advanced antiAliasType and setting sharpness = 400 didn't fix the problem the fonts are still blured

Comment: @KonstantinDjenkov hmm. I have no other suggestion. Sorry that didn't help. You aren't embedding it or one of its containers as a bitmap are you? Again not sure if that would do anything. I guess I would just suggest making a super simple replica of this problem with only a single textField in the display list and see if you still get the same issue.